# Why would a Static Block that contains an image hang/timeout on save?

Tags: magento-1, static-block

I'm troubleshooting an issue with Static Blocks.

When I create a new Static Block with an image, it works fine, but if I then go back into the Static Block to edit it, even without making any changes, it will hang/timeout on save.

Static Blocks without images are working fine.

The error that I'm receiving after about a minute is in a Nginx "502 Bad Gateway", which is closely related to "504 Gateway Timeout".

The code for my Static Block is below.

---

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <a href="/some-page">
            <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/carousel-image.jpg"}}" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Do you have any idea why a Static Block with an image hang/timeout on saving?

Comment: If you take out the `{{}}` directive does it save properly?

Comment: @benmarks It did not make a difference. Even if I remove the src completely, it still hangs: <img src="" />

Even if I remove the entire image tag, it still hangs.

However, if I create a Static Block without an image, I have no problem editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem in my case was to add an entry like the one below to the hosts file on the server:

209.xxx.xxx.xx www.mymagentosite.com

The server could not make http requests to itself because it cannot find www.mymagentosite.com.

Someone who had solved a similar issue gave me the hint that I needed. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/441051/loopback-connection-via-phps-getimage-size-crashes-server-magentos-cms

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 <img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/carousel-image.jpg'}}" />
```

Comment: Going from double quotes to single quotes didn't change anything. Even if I remove the src completely, it still hangs: <img src="" /> Even if I remove the entire image tag, it still hangs. However, if I create a Static Block without an image, I have no problem editing it.